# Is syskey enabled just by running it? or will it ever show a disabled state?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, encryption, syskey

So, my aunt had some scammers call her and long story short, her computer was syskey'd.

I've factory reset the machine 3 times now, and every time I fire up syskey to check it, it's still enabled.

Does syskey enable just by simply running it? or does it need to be invoked by manually enabling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, syskey is enabled *by default* starting with Windows 2000 (if I remember correctly).

You never notice it because the default mode is to simply hide the encryption key within the same registry hive (which was perhaps effective for the first month or so, until everyone figured it out).

The only time you'll see it completely disabled is if you run Windows NT 4.

Comment: So, to be clear, it's normal that when I launch syskey, it's already in the enabled state, even though I did not enable it?

Comment: @level42 That's correct.

Comment: That's awesome, and saves me a lot of stressing out for no reason. Thanks!